# android: extend the listitem click range

Tags: android, click, range, extend, listitem

I have implemented a ExpanddableListView in my android application, but I'm not happy with the click range of the child items.
The OnCLickListener only gets triggered when I click excactly on the String that is my list item.

How can I extend the click range of the listitem to the whole row?

Here is my layout-xml "selectreasonlist_item.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:clickable="false" android:focusable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my Activity I have:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selectreason);
    final Context context = this;

    //Get the ListView
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.xlvSelectReason);

    //Preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader,listDataChild);

    //Setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    //Setting OnClickListener to child item
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

       //My Code

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help
Cheers Nik

Comment: I found out that I have to configure android:padding in order to extend the click range. I added             android:paddingRight="130dp" to my list_item.xml layout. Solved. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach listener to the list using [setOnGroupClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnGroupClickListener(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener)) and [setOnChildClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnChildClickListener(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener)) to handle its events to the listeners [OnGroupClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener.html) and [OnChildClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html).

Comment: I saw you put false to clickable on TextView, but have you removed OnCLickListener as you mentioned on the question?

Comment: No, I have my OnChildClickListener set in the Activity. The Override method "onChildClick()" returns false... Does the function setChildIndicatorBounds(int, int) help me?

Comment: The default behavior of setOnGroupClickListener and setOnChildClickListener is to cover the entire row, you are probably picking the click event somewhere else or maybe your list is not covering the entire width you want.

Comment: Just a note: fill_parent is deprecated at Android 2.2, if you are not targeting an api lower than this you should use match_parent instead.

Comment: Thanks for info. I have added the code from my activity to the thread - as you can see I have a custom adapter class: Can that cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I have to configure android:padding in order to extend the click range. 
I added

```
android:paddingRight="130dp"
```

to my list_item.xml layout. Solved. ;)